# Webform not passing the correct value to search for a MYSQL record

Tags: php, webforms

I've got a problem with a webform that uses PHP.  I'm sure it's very obvious but can't find the problem.

What I want to do is basically enter a numerical value into a field on a form, which then sends the value to a mysql database, requesting a record linked to that value,

The problem I am getting is that the value is not being taken properly when I hit the 'submit' button, but will take the previous value that was submitted a previous query.

For example, I want to retrieve a record that has an 'id' of 1. I enter '1' into the field (the id of the field is 'identry'), but I get an error.  The error basically signifies that I have not entered a value into the 'id' field for some reason.  Then I access the search field again, enter a value of '2', and hit the 'submit'.  I then get a result that it has just accessed record with 'id' of '1' (the previous query!!!!)

Any ideas??

This is my code for the form.....

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" >
          <table width="400" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td width = "150" ><div align="right">HPOV reference </div></td>   
              <td width = "150"><label>
              <input name= "identry" type="text" id="identry" />
              </label></td>
              <td width = "100"><label>
                <div align="left">
                <input name="Submit" type="submit" onclick="MM_openBrWindow('HPOVwindow.php?id=<?php echo $_POST['identry']; ?>','','toolbar=yes,width=1000,height=1000')" />
                </div>
                </label></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </form>
```

I think its how I submit the variables in the first instance but can't find out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're posting the previous entry when you submit your form.

PHP can't handle data on the client side until it's sent to the server.

This line: `<?php echo $_POST['identry']; ?>` is telling PHP to fill the value that was posted to it, which would be the previous entry.  What you meant was: `document.getElementById("identry").value`

Edit: So the line that enters the value would look something like this:

```
<input name="Submit" type="submit" onclick="MM_openBrWindow('HPOVwindow.php?id=" + document.getElementById("identry").value + "','','toolbar=yes,width=1000,height=1000')" />
```

and just try the following:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" >
          <table width="400" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td width = "150" ><div align="right">HPOV reference </div></td>   
              <td width = "150"><label>
              <input name= "identry" type="text" id="identry" />
              </label></td>
              <td width = "100"><label>
                <div align="left">
                <input name="Submit" type="submit" onclick="submitForm();" /> 
                </div>
                </label></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <script>
          function submitForm() {
                     window.open('HPOVwindow.php?id=' + document.getElementById("identry").value,'','toolbar=yes,width=1000,height=1000');
                                 return false;


          }
        </script>
      </form>
```

Comment: I added the full file (basically put the submission in a function and tested it, it should work for you).

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant.  Thank you very much.  That worked perfectly.